# How to enable two functions to hide each other's main task along with running their own main task assigned to them?

Tags: javascript, html

I've two functions showABC() and showXYZ() assigned to two different buttons "Button 1" and "Button 2" respectively. I want "Button 1" to display the text "ABC" and "Button 2" to display the text "XYZ" and then hide the already displayed text "ABC" and vice versa in case of "Button 1" when clicked for the 2nd time. I hope you get my point.

I have tried the following code which includes style.display property to hide the other function's task. But when I click either of the two buttons, it shows the text "ABC" and "XYZ" together. Need your help!!

```js
function showABC() {
var x = document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = "ABC";
var y = showXYZ();
if (y.style.display === "block") {y.style.display = "none";}
}

function showXYZ() {
var x = document.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML = "XYZ";
var y =showABC();
if (y.style.display === "block") {y.style.display = "none";}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>

<p id="abc"></p>
<p id="xyz"></p>

<button id="btn1" onclick="showABC()">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="showXYZ()">Button 2</button>
```

Comment: function showABC calls showXYZ and showXYZ calls showABC and showABC calls showXYZ and showXYZ calls showABC and ......

Comment: @epascarello What will be the solution for my desired result?

Comment: not sure what is complicated about it. Just set the other one to be hidden. No need to call the other method...

Comment: @epascarello I'm a beginner, can you please edit my snippet as it should be for the desired result?

Comment: `var elem = document.getElementById("abc");
elem.innerHTML = "ABC";
elem.style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("xyz").style.display = "none";`

Comment: @epascarello your code isn't working as desired. Now when I click Button 1 for the first time, it shows the text ABC but when after I click Button 2 and Button 1 respectively, it shows nothing.

Comment: Well that is because you would need to reverse it for the other one... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code you are looking for:

```
function showElement(name, value) {
    var x = document.getElementById(name);
    x.innerHTML = value;
    x.style.display = "block";
}
function hideElement(name) {
    var x = document.getElementById(name);
    x.style.display = "none";
}

function showXYZ() {
    showElement("xyz", "XYZ");
    hideElement("abc");
}

function showABC() {
    showElement("abc", "ABC");
    hideElement("xyz");
}
```

Comment: WOW! it solved my problem. That's what I thought I was missing. The function with 2 arguments. Now my code is working like a charm! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So many ways to accomplish the desired result. As mentioned in some comments, you could use css display to hide one and show the other. You could also just empty the contents of the one you don't want visible. It would also help to setup some variables here.

```
//
var abc = document.getElementById("abc"),
    xyz = document.getElementById("xyz");


//
function showABC() {
    abc.innerHTML = "ABC";
    xyz.innerHTML = "";

    //or...
    //abc.style.display = "block";
    //xyz.style.display = "none";
}

//
function showXYZ() {
    xyz.innerHTML = "XYZ";
    abc.innerHTML = "";

    //or...
    //xyz.style.display = "block";
    //abc.style.display = "none";
}
```

On another note, you could also use one div, which would save you some time.

```
<div id="copy"></div>

//
var copy = document.getElementById("copy");


//
function showABC() {
    copy.innerHTML = "ABC";
}

//
function showXYZ() {
    copy.innerHTML = "XYZ";
}
```

Comment: I have tried your first solution by declaring abc and xyz both inside and outside of the function with style.display property. But now the buttons aren't working at all.

Comment: You'll have to debug why... console.log() is your friend here. Are the click handlers on the buttons working? Are the functions being called? You have to figure out what is not working and why. Part of the game